# Python and seleniumrequests getting request headers

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, python-requests

I need to get a cookie from a specific request. Problem is it gets generated outside my eyes and i need to use Selenium to simulate browser open so i can generate it myself. The second problem is that i can't access the request cookie. The cookie i need is in the request, not the response.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get('http://www.princess.com/find/searchResults.do')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="LSV010"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button')[0].click()
```

This code block opens the page and on the second result, clicks the "View all dates and pricing" link. The cookie is sent there but by the browser, not as a response. I need to get my hands on that cookie. Other libraries are ok if they can do the job.
If you go manually to the page, this is the thing i need:
[image]
I have selected the request and the Cookie i need and as it shows it is in the request not response. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: so you want to check cookies?

Comment: cookie in the request that browser sends. The url that the `.click()` calls is `http://www.princess.com/find/viewAllCruises.do` and the cookie i need always starts with `_aeu=QCQ=;`.

Comment: do you need to send a request to website with specific cookie, or do you want to check the cookie ? what is your requirement. sorry but it's really confusing.

Comment: Yes, i need to send the request triggered by the lick i `click()` with a specific cookie i cannot generate otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how this is done. Using the `selenium` library i did manage to get this working:

```
def fix_header():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe', firefox_profile=profile)
    browser.get('https://www.princess.com/find/searchResults.do')
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@class='expand-table view-all-link util-link plain-text-btn gotham-bold']")
    WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='expand-table view-all-link util-link plain-text-btn gotham-bold']")))
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@class='expand-table view-all-link util-link plain-text-btn gotham-bold']").click()
    except Exception:
        browser.find_element_by_class_name('mfp-close').click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@class='expand-table view-all-link util-link plain-text-btn gotham-bold']").click()

    cookies = browser.get_cookies()
    browser.close()
    chrome_cookie = ''
    for c in cookies:
        chrome_cookie += c['name']
        chrome_cookie += '='
        chrome_cookie += c['value']
        chrome_cookie += "; "
    return chrome_cookie[:-2]
```

`Selenium` actually goes to the page and "clicks" the `url` i need with a browser and gets the needed cookies.

Comment: To turn this a little pretty `chrome_cookie = '; '.join(["{}:{}".format(c['name'], c['value']) for c in cookies])`